# How do I select 5 random rows from the 20 most recent rows?

Tags: mysql

I want to select 5 random rows from a table but only from the 20 most recent rows. I know the 2 statements separately would be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 20
```

How would I combine these 2 statements so it will select 5 random rows from the 20 most recent rows? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an nested select

```
 SELECT foo.* FROM (SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 20 ) as foo 
         ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5
```

Comment: This one is the only answer that works, btw. Without using "as foo" and "foo." it doesn't work. Do you know why this is?

Comment: @user1413341 MySQL requires that all derived tables and subqueries have their own alias. It's what I get for trying to type quick enough to compete with these two. =P

Answer (score 1):

Simply nest them:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 20
) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Look up subqueries!

```
SELECT d.* FROM (SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 20) as d ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5;
```